# Replacing first occurrence of character with one character and the second with another character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a table with a column Name that can contain substring surrounding with quotations ..."substring"... 
For each row in this table I need to replace first occurrence of " with « and second one with »
Each row can contain only one quoted substring.

So if I have a record like this 'fgh"abc"sdf' I want to get this 'fgh«abc»sdf'

I can't come up with a solution for this.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Does it support regex replacement? If not (and maybe even if) two passes with a regular string replacement action may be easier to manage.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server 2012. maybe I could do it with a help of PATINDEX. thanks for your advice!

Comment: you should post an example of what the record looks like currently and what you would like it to be.

Comment: If the quotes are at the beginning and end of the record, there's no need for regex at all. Just simple substring to get the text without quotes and then surround that with the new quotes you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First an example of how the syntax works

```
DECLARE @a varchar(max) = 'fgh"abc"sdf'

SELECT 
  stuff(stuff(@a, charindex('"', @a),1, '«'), 
    charindex('"', @a, charindex('"', @a) + 1), 1, '»')
```

Result:

```
fgh«abc»sdf
```

This is the query needed where col is the name of your column:

```
SELECT 
  stuff(stuff(col, charindex('"', col),1, '«'), 
    charindex('"', col, charindex('"', col) + 1), 1, '»')
FROM yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like :

```
DECLARE @TmpVar VARCHAR(100)
SET @TmpVar = 'haha"substring"hehe'
SET @TmpVar = STUFF(@TmpVar, CHARINDEX('"', @TmpVar), 1, '«')
SET @TmpVar = REPLACE(@TmpVar, '"', '»')
```