# Replace characters from given string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

String = "Vishal Hariharan" .. Replace first "H" with "A" SQL

I have one scenario where I want replace only first "H" character among others "H" positions and remaining keep as it is.

Comment: There is no question here. You have not shown any attempt to solve the problem yourself. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   A simple search for ` [sql-server] replace first occurrence` would yield this as the first result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986902/replacing-first-occurrence-of-character-with-one-character-and-the-second-with-a

Comment: And yet the answer you have linked to, as well as many other answers to similar questions on SO are incorrect as they do not take into account the case where the character being searched for does not exist in the string.

Comment: @MarkE Well, I would say those other answers on SO are limited or incomplete, but not incorrect. We don't know OP's full requirements *because they weren't stated*. The question doesn't say "I found by reading other answers that I can replace the first occurrence of a substring with the `stuff` function, but it doesn't work when my string doesn't have the targeted substring in it". It is nice that you have gone out of your way to provide a full answer, especially when the OP showed no initiative, but I wasn't feeling so generous.

Comment: @All .. thank you for answering... I was trying to do with STUFF , given answer corrected me.

Answer (score 2):

There are many simplistic answers for this on Stack Overflow that don't take into account the case where the character being searched for doesn't exist in the string. In these cases, the SQL will return NULL if the replacement character does not exist in the string. Try this instead:

```
declare @name varchar(max), @ToReplace varchar(max), @ReplaceWith varchar(max)
set @name = 'Vishal Hariharan'
set @ToReplace = 'H'
set @ReplaceWith = 'A'
select @name
select stuff(@name, charindex(@ToReplace,@name),1, CASE WHEN charindex(@ToReplace,@name) <> 0 THEN @ReplaceWith ELSE @ToReplace END)
```

The `CASE` statement simply checks if the character exists in the string, and if it doesn't, it replaces the matching character with itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @findChar varchar(max)='H'
DECLARE @RepalceCharacter varchar(max)='A'
DECLARE @OriginText varchar(max)='Vishal Hariharan'

IF (CharIndex(@findChar, @OriginText)<>0)
    SELECT Stuff(@OriginText, CharIndex(@findChar, @OriginText), Len(@findChar), @RepalceCharacter)
ELSE
SELECT @OriginText
```